# C++ Decimal to Binary, how to convert it?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

long long decimal_to_binary(int n) {
    long long bn = 0;
    int rem, i = 1;

    while (n != 0) {
        rem = n % 2;
        n /= 2;
        bn += rem * i;
        i *= 10; 
    }
    return bn;
}
    int main(){
    int a,b,c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    cout << decimal_to_binary(a) << " " << std::oct << a << " " << std::hex << a << '\n';
    cout << decimal_to_binary(b) << " " << std::oct << b << " " << std::hex << b << '\n';
    cout << decimal_to_binary(c) << " " << std::oct << c << " " << std::hex << c << '\n';
}
```

You enter 3 decimal numbers and print them in binary, octal and hex.

When I enter **2,8,15** it should print:

> 10 2 2
>
> 1000 10 8
>
> 1111 17 F

but it prints

> 10 2 2
>
> 3e8 10 8
>
> 457 17 f

Can you point out what i'm missing?

Comment: Try `cout << std::dec << decimal_to_binary(a)...`.

Answer (score 4):

In general, when someone is talking about "decimal" or "binary" they're talking about the **text** representation of a value, not the internal representation. While you can hack around with the value and maybe create an integer value that can be displayed so it looks like a binary value, that's not particularly useful. What you need to do is convert the integer value to **text** that represents its binary value:

```
std::string to_binary(unsigned i) {
    std::string result;
    while (i != 0) {
        if (i % 2)
            result.append(1, '1');
        else
            result.append(1, '0');
        i /= 2;
    }
    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << to_binary(3) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

If you need to display a value as decimal, octal, or hexadecimal, you can do that more directly with a stream manipulator:

```
std::cout << std::hex << 3 << '\n'; // display value as hex
std::cout << std::dec << 3 << '\n'; // display value as decimal
std::cout << std::oct << 3 << '\n'; // display value as octal
```

There's no manipulator for displaying values as binary, however, so you have to roll your own.

Comment: result.insert (0,'1'); etc maybe easier than appending and then reversing.

Comment: @Owl -- there are lots of ways to write that code. I don't know what "easier" refers to in your comment, but inserting at the beginning, which certainly works, does a lot of thrashing because it has to move all the characters each time a new one is generated. The main purpose of this answer, though, is to point out that the primary concern is generating a text representation.

Comment: Yes, that's true, maybe in an ideal world you'd calculate a base 2 log, to determine how many digits it has, then do an in placement character insert into an array of predetermined length.

Comment: @Owl -- using a C-style array is actually easier here. You know the maximum length that the result can have, because you know the size of the integer type. So you start at the end of the array, with a '\0'`, and then fill in digits working backwards until the remaining value is 0. But that's too complicated to explain in an answer to a beginner, and either filling backwards then reversing, as I did, or inserting as you generate digits, as you suggested, is easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, i'm totally knitpicking anyway :) But that's exactly what i did i used a sizeof and then worked backwards from there using bitshifts and &s to get the digits.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `std::bitset` to get binary representation of a number as a string:

```
std::string decimal_to_binary(int n) {
  return std::bitset<32>(n).to_string();
}
```

Your current implementation will fail miserably on any somewhat big number (at least because `long long` wouldn't be able to hold more than ~18 decimal places or bits in your case).

See how it works here: https://ideone.com/hDNWbe

Comment: Ok, but the task is from HackerRank and my teacher said it must pass the test case. Yours didn't as it has '0' before the actual number.

Comment: @НедялкоАнгелов you didn't specify that. It's easily corrected just by stripping leading zeroes of a string, i.e. `auto s = std::bitset<32>(n).to_string(); return s.substr(s.find('1'));`: https://ideone.com/mx4ssc